# How to autoreload Jinja2 templates using nginx, uswgi and flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, jinja2, uwsgi

I've setup a linux server at home running flask->uwsgi->nginx. It works well and auto reloads properly when I modify python sources because I added --py-autoreload option to the uswgi command, but the problem is that when I change the html/css templates that Jinja uses, it won't auto-reload.

Do you have any idea how I could do that ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the TEMPLATE_AUTO_RELOAD configuration flag to true.

```
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

This auto-checks for changes in your templates and reloads the files. Have a look at the [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/#builtin-configuration-values) for details.